# Simple email address check using preg_match

Tags: regex

I have a simple regular expression for finding email addresses in a text, but even though I don't see an error, it doesn't work.

```
$addr=array();
$t='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean fermentum risus id tortor. Morbi leo mi, nonummy eget tristique non, rhoncus non leo. Donec quis nibh at felis congue commodo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos aaa@bbb.com. Aliquam ccc@ddd.net ornare wisi eu metus.';
if(preg_match_all('~[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}~',$t,$addr, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
  echo 'found';
}
```

I have also tried this version I found, but it didn't work either:

```
if(preg_match_all('/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/',$t,$addr, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching emails that are all uppercase. You need to either do `[A-Za-z]`, or set the case insensitive flag on `preg_match`

Comment: Right, I forgot the "i" modifier, but does this code really work for you?

Comment: You didn't add a-z to the last part.

Comment: <?php
$addr=array();
$t='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean fermentum risus id tortor. Morbi leo mi, nonummy eget tristique non, rhoncus non leo. Donec quis nibh at felis congue commodo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos aaa@bbb.com. Aliquam ccc@ddd.net ornare wisi eu metus.';
if(preg_match_all('~[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}~',$t,$addr, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
echo 'found';
}
?>

Comment: Oh, I had some troubles with my FTP. os it was delayedand I didn't see the current version, it's OK now.

Answer (score 1):

This would also work for the match pattern and is shortest:

`[0-z.%-]+@[0-z.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}`

This works because `0-z` covers `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `_`, also A-z covers A-Z and a-z

I develop in ruby and you can see this 'in action' at http://rubular.com/r/PdbH1BjWMs

Answer (score 0):

Include the lower case letter class:

```
if(preg_match_all('~[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}~',$t,$addr, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
  echo 'found';
}
```

...note *a-z*.